# Unable to set the hidden property of the range class run time error '1003'

Tags: excel, vba

I have code in this module:

```
Sub HideSalTable()

User = Worksheets("log").Range("R1").Value
If User = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SSSSSS").Range("za1").Value Then
Columns("S:AA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

ElseIf User = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SSSSSS").Range("za3").Value Then
Columns("S:AA").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

ElseIf User = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SSSSSS").Range("za4").Value Then
Columns("S:AA").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End If

End Sub
```

I have a button to redirect me to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SSSSSS") with this code:

```
Private Sub Change_SSSSSS_Button_Click()

 Dim pass1 As String
  Dim pass2 As String
  pass1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SSSSSS").Range("za3").Value
   pass2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SSSSSS").Range("za4").Value
  Dim Inp
    Dim lTries As Long



    lTries = 1
    Do
        Inp = InputBoxDK("enter password", "Zmhnk")
        If Inp = "" Or Inp = vbCancel Then Exit Sub          '* Cancel button pressed or nothing entered
        If Inp = (pass1) Or Inp = (pass2) Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        lTries = lTries + 1
        If lTries > 4 Then
            MsgBox "Error", vbInformation, "Zmhnk"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            If MsgBox("try again", vbYesNo, "error_Zmhnk") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Sheets("SSSSSS").Visible = True
 Sheets("SSSSSS").Activate

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The problem is when the user presses the button with the 2nd code I face an error and I don't know why.

The error:

```
Unable to set the hidden property of the range class run time error '1003'
```

Answer (score 14):

Two things

1) You have not fully qualified your range. I understand that you are getting redirected but this is much safer.

```
Columns("S:AA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Change it to

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SSSSSS").Columns("S:AA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

2) I believe your worksheet is protected. You have to unprotect it. You can do that as follows

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SSSSSS").Unprotect "myPassword"
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, Can I also emphasize that you MUST specify .EntireColumn/Row- although it's not the OP's problem, and it's in your answer, there must be plenty of guys like me that came direct from google looking for this response

Comment: Sheet protection was the cause for me

Answer (score 0):

when you have the control from the Form there is no Problem

 but if you have it from the worksheet itself then it works actually but with Error:1004 
so just use ( On Error Resume Next)

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim wsMon As Worksheet
Set wsMon = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Montag")
On Error Resume Next
Select Case ComboBox1.ListIndex
       Case 0
            xHide (False)
            wsMon.Rows("12:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            xHide (True)
       Case 1
            xHide (False)
            wsMon.Rows("12:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            wsMon.Rows("19:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            xHide (True)
       Case 2
            xHide (False)
            wsMon.Rows("12:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            xHide (True)
End Select

End Sub
```

xHide is a Boolean Function :
true

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

or False

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue (only the error code was 1004, but the error message was the same). What solved the issue at my Excel sheet was to remove a comment which was within the range that I tried to hide. It seems like comments are not allowed within the range that should be hidden.